# powering android phone from 3 AA battery directly (not USB!)

Tags: batteries, android, mobile, nimh, lithium-polymer

I have Sony Arc phone which was spoiled by me (story OutTopic) as it won't charge lion battery anymore. the phone itself works perfectly. I don't want to do the regular 3AA to USB charger way. Trying to use 3 NiMH in the battery pins of the phone. Getting in ranges 3.7V+ from my 3 rechargables. Original sony li-polymer battery says 1500mA - 5.6Wh.

The phone starts with the logo. Does Experia animation and reboot and starts again in loops.

I suspect my battery is not giving enough current or voltage for android OS to start loading.
I was wondering if I can put the phone on 4AA NiMH meaning ~5V, will it burn the phone forever (just thinking).

Could not find notes on internet about trying this. everyone does USB route. Please suggest what options can help my case?

Answer (score 3):

Four cells will put you over the nominal voltage of a single Li-Ion cell and it might be OK considering they will use a switch-down converter. However that is not guaranteed, it may damage the phone, it may have over-voltage protection that will prevent it starting up or worst case may have some form of clamps that will damage your batteries and/or cause a hazard.

Personally I'd go down the well documented 5V USB path (if that will still operate the phone). Considering the exact design of the phone's power control will be proprietary I think without test equipment the only other alternative would be to try it and and see what happens, accepting it could damage the phone and keep checking that the batteries don't get too hot due to excess current draw.

However it would be preferable to purchase at least a cheap multimeter to check the current being drawn just in case it does have clamps of some form. And even better would be a current limited power supply if you have access to one to see what happens as the voltage is ramped up.

Edit: Another thought would be to say put a 1A fuse in series. That should prevent any prolonged over current condition likely to be a hazard regarding the batteries, although the phone could still be damaged.

Comment: thank for tips. I have a multimeter, i only know to check voltage. i dont know how to check the current drawn by the phone.

Comment: @thevikas, I just addded another idea regarding a fuse, but as mentioned would help protect the phone if things 'go badly'.

Comment: The 'USB path' will be the better idea because it can be expected to have voltage regulation &c. inside and should be more tolerant to different voltages.